# Como pegar botão clicado que foi criado dinamicamente

Tags: php, jquery

Bom dia.

Eu estou criando um botão dinamicamente via uma resposta de um sql.

```
  $this->return.='<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                            <input type="button" id="btnSegundaEtapa" class="btn btn-success green pull-right" value="Proximo" name="btnSegundaEtapa">
                        </div>

                    </div>';
```

Ai eu estou pegando da seguinte forma

```
$("#btnSegundaEtapa").on('click',function () {
    console.log("Ooooi");
});
```

Comment: Tens de usar `$(document).on('click','#btnSegundaEtapa', function () {`. Estás a usar `#btnSegundaEtapa` mais que 1 vez?

Comment: Não, apenas dessa vez

Comment: Ok, boa! Linkei uma pergunta que responde à tua pergunta, basicamente o que coloquei no comentário.

Comment: Beleza, meu caro, deu certinho, valeu